# How to automatically adapt a websites zoomlevel to a fixed text-size?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I'm using Chrome and know that I can manually change the zoom level of any webpage.  But since the font and its size changes between sites, I have to do it far too often, so I am sick of it.

Is there a Browser Extension for Chrome that does that for me? My goal is to have a consistent text size on all pages I visit. That would save me lots of effort and help my eyes, esp. when reading long articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no such tool because there is a lot of different things that play into the displayed text size.

You can easily adjust the zoom level using your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and your mouse wheel. In addition you could adjust your Chrome settings and change the default font, zoom level and text size. In addition there are High DPI settings available within Windows that should also affect the display of websites.

Comment: Thanks, for the tips and telling the harsh truth. 
But manually zooming is annoying and changing default zoom so that all is bigger doesn't solve the issue, since it just zooms every page equally. But I want that the outliners, which have either to big or small text, are equalized to a reference text size.

Answer (score 0):

Many extensions from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/font?_category=extensions would achieve that, if using a Readability extension is a slight overkill solution.

Comment: I looked through some of them, but can't find any that automatically zooms any website so that text always has the same size. For example this site would be zoomded bigger since the text is a bit smaller than on most sites.